# SQL : group by clause with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a select statement to retrieve the rows with names and status only for a particular tid with the most recent dateended

the table schema looks like

```
ID              int 
Name            varchar(100)    
TID             int 
DateStarted     datetime    
DateEnded       datetime    
Status          int 
TestQueueTable  varchar(50) 
TQDID           int 
ResultsFile     varchar(255)    
TextResultsFile varchar(255)
```

When I write select

```
select name,status,max(dateended)  
from testcasedata 
where tid='87946' 
group by name,status
```

the rows retrieved are as below

```
name                                   status     max(dateended)
=====================================================================
IntegrationPlumbingTest              2            2013-09-19 09:24:30.000 
LCEventLogger                        2            2013-09-19 09:23:52.000 
NonReferralGQ_1                      2            2013-09-19 09:23:06.000 
NonReferralGQ_2                      2            2013-09-19 09:22:48.000 
ApplyToJobFromTGAndVerifyFrom_A      3            2013-09-20 02:17:54.000 
PostReqAndVerifyFrom_A               3            2013-09-20 01:47:33.000 
PostReqAndVerifyFrom_B               3            2013-09-20 02:04:09.000 
Verify_UploadResume                  3            2013-09-19 12:21:49.000 
ApplyToJobFromAndVerifyFrom_B        2            2013-09-19 03:24:67.000 
ApplyToJobFromAndVerifyFrom_B        3            2013-09-20 02:23:05.000
```

Here I should actually display only the distinct name and status where if the status for a name contains 2 it should should display only that row otherwise it should display name and status group by the `max(dateended)`

even the last two records

```
ApplyToJobFromAndVerifyFrom_B        2            2013-09-19 03:24:67.000 
ApplyToJobFromAndVerifyFrom_B        3            2013-09-20 02:23:05.000
```

should also be grouped into one with the latest date.

finally from the table i want the name,status,dateended records without any repetitions with the maxdate

can you please tell me how to proceed..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you edit your question to include what you want the result to be, so we can see how it is different from your current attempt?

Comment: *"...if the status for a name contains 2 it should should display only that row.."* It looks like that's exactly what it's doing now. *"...otherwise it should display name and status group by the max(dateended)..."* And it looks like that's exactly what it's doing now.

Comment: Is this correct? "If if a name has no status 2, its last entry should be displayed, otherwise the status 2 entry should be displayed instead." If so, what if there are two or more status 2 entries per name? Should the results have all of them or just one (per name)? If one, then which one?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not working as you want because you're grouping by `name` and `status`, so actually you need last record for each `name` order by `dateended desc`. You can use `row_number()` approach:

```
with cte as (
    select
        name, status, dateended,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by dateended desc) as rn
    from testcasedata 
    where tid='87946' 
)
select
    name, status, dateended
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.here if the name contains the status as 2 it should display that row though it is not the recent date..otherwise if the status is anything other than 2 then it should display the status with max date...any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select 
    name,
    (select top 1 status from testcasedata where tid = t.tid order by dateended desc) as status,
    max(dateended)  
from testcasedata as t
where tid='87946' 
group by 
    name
```

Comment: not very elegant, what if you have more columns to fetch? It's also have not very good performance. row_number() approach is much more useful in SQL Server.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I gave you +1 :) But, this is also still operational solution, and in case of little tables, performance will be minor.